# Stored procedure versioning in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are developing complex application which is divided into nodes and instances. It is possible that each instance on node will use a different version of the same-named stored procedure.

We would like to know what is the best way to version stored procedures in SQL Server. For now I made it by schema. For example:

First version of procedure:

```
[0].[GetFirstNames]
```

Second version of procedure:

```
[1].[GetFirstNames]
```

Is this the right way to do it?

I was thinking also about:

```
[dbo].[GetFirstNames0] and [dbo].[GetFirstNames1]
```

Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: Why not using a version control system ? Using `schema` or different `stored procedure` name will affect your client application

Comment: Because I have to have possibility to have two version of procedure on the same time.

Comment: any advices ?:)